# Prototype replace method giving null error

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm new to prototype, but fairly experienced with jQuery so it could just be I'm misunderstanding how prototype works. I'm trying to do the following

`$$("tr.total_line td.total_cell").first().replace(newTotal);`

but I'm getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null`

When I execute `$$("tr.total_line td.total_cell").first()` in the JS console I get a DOM element result.

Here's the relevant markup

```
<tr class="total_line">
    <td colspan="2">Total</td>
    <td class="total_cell">$50.00</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What is `newTotal`? I tried to replicate the problem in Chrome, but instead of breaking it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `.first()` is returning a `<td>` element, you'll need to insert a `<td>` or `<th>` in order for the replacement to be valid HTML.

So if `newTotal` is:

```
"<td>$100</td>"
```

...it should work. But if it is just:

```
"$100"
```

...it doesn't.

Or another option would be to replace the `innerHTML` of the `<td>`:

```
$$("tr.total_line td.total_cell").first().innerHTML = newTotal;
```

Comment: This turned out to be it. I got used to jQuery giving me wrapped objects, rather than DOM elements so I didn't realize that I need to use DOM properties. `innerHTML` didn't work, but `innerText` did for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

If `replace` continues to cause problems you can try `update` instead which works in a similar way.